# Derivative of power series :

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives

> If $ m  ∈ ]0,1[ $ and $ f(x)=\sum_{k>=1}\frac{m^kx^k}{k}$, $-1/m < x < 1/m,$ 
>   then $ f'(1)$ equals to:
>
> a) $m$ b) $0$ c) $m/(1+m)$ d) $1/(1-m)$ e) $m/(1-m)$

I tried solving it and got

$$ f(x)=\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{m^kx^k}{k},$$
$$ f'(x)=\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{m^kkx^{k-1}}{k},$$
$$ f'(1)=\sum_{k\geq 1}{m^k1^{k-1}}$$

Now, what should I do? Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 3):

Note that $m\in (0,1)$ and the [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) is convergent:
$$f'(1)=\sum_{k\geq 1}{m^k1^{k-1}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{m^k}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{m(1-m^n)}{1-m}=\frac{m}{1-m}.$$

Comment: Hello, Robert! Thank you! I just didn't understand everything. Why did you multiply "m*lim sum m^k? I am missing something!

Comment: @VivianeF I edit my answer. Note that $1-m^n=(1-m)(1+m+m^2+\dots +m^{n-1})$. Is it better know?